# Debugging OpenLDAP when using SSL/TLS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openldap

I have `slapd` version: 2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.3 spun up on Ubuntu 14.04. It's configured for TLS over port 389, as well as SSL on 636.

I've run into a query problem testing a new application and not quite sure how to debug it. I can run `tcpdump` on the ldap server but unless I drop port 389 to cleartext, it's not much use.  I really don't want to do that as any passwords used in the test app are basically compromised from a security standpoint. The only thing I can think of is restarting `slapd` with `-D 255` or something but would really like to get a look at the session data between the client and server.

How can I get a look at the data being transferred between the PHP app and the ldap server without compromising the session integrity?  There is very little that turns up in `/var/log/` files.

UPDATE: 
I added extra logging for my `cn=config` setup like this:

write the following to logmod.ldif:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcLogLevel
olcLogLevel: stats

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcLogLevel
olcLogLevel: stats2
```

Then run:

```
sudo ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f logmod.ldif
```

Comment: Load your tcpdump capture in WireShark with the LDAP servers private key and you can [dissect SSL](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) and decrypt the traffic.

Comment: @HBruijn This may not work if using forward security ciphers DHE/ECDHE.

Comment: @HBruijn This is just what I want but not sure I can make total sense of the docs. Am I supposed to follow the cert creation under "Complete SSL decryption walk through" or is that a just showing a way of decrypting HTTPS traffic? Not sure why I'd need to serve "privkey.pem" via localhost when I've already fed it to Wireshark SSL protocol preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to set `olcLogLevel` to include `stats` and `stats2`. This will cause OpenLDAP to log query and response information to syslog facility `LOCAL4`.

You will also need to ensure that `LOCAL4` is sent to somewhere you can read it, e.g. make `/etc/rsyslog.d/slapd.conf` and have it contain `local4.*    /var/log/messages`.

Comment: This is great info, thanks. I'll update my question to include what I did to modify the logging.

Comment: Using replace twice will not have the desired results, as the second replace will overwrite the first. Either put both directives on one line or add/replace them both at once. Using the same ldif is not sufficient. It must also be the same entry.

Comment: Ah, good catch. changed second `replace` -> `add`